# why does this query work with one table but times out with the other table

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

ok i have 3 tables in question:

```
`eng` with column english
`jap` with column japanese
`eng-jap` with column eng and column jap
```

eng.english is a unique english sentence, 
jap.japanese is a unique japanese sentence,
eng-jap is a translation containing one japanese from jap and one english from eng

i pasted more details of the tables at the bottom of this question.

MY QUESTION: why does...

this query works lighting fast:

```
SELECT * FROM eng WHERE english IN (SELECT eng FROM `eng-jap`);
```

while this one takes 100 secs or times out:

```
SELECT * FROM jap WHERE japanese IN (SELECT jap FROM `eng-jap`);
```

(a strange note about this 2nd query is that if i do it in phpmyadmin, it takes 100secs before it finishes 'if it finishes' then it will SAY it took 0.024secs. though it loaded for 100secs, also on my website it takes the 100secs or times out)

all 3 of these tables have roughly the same number of rows as you will see from the data below. the eng and jap tables are especially similar.

i suspect the problem is somewhere in the table settings or index or something so i will paste all the pertinent details now:

```
JAP TABLE:

Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   
PRIMARY BTREE   Yes     No      ID          130296      A       
full    BTREE   Yes     No      japanese    130296      A       

Format  dynamic
Collation   utf8_general_ci
Rows    130,296
Row length ø    264
Row size ø  372 B
Next Autoindex  131,790

Type    Usage
Data    33,718.6    KiB
Index   13,652.0    KiB
Total   47,370.6    KiB

ENG TABLE:

Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation
PRIMARY BTREE   Yes     No      ID      129637      A
full    BTREE   Yes     No      english 129637      A

Format  dynamic
Collation   utf8_general_ci
Rows    129,637
Row length ø    101
Row size ø  181 B
Next Autoindex  130,749

Data    12,899.3    KiB
Index   10,068.0    KiB
Total   22,967.3    KiB

ENG_JAP TABLE:
Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation
PRIMARY BTREE   Yes     No      ID          139442  A
eng     BTREE   Yes     No      eng (150)       0   A
                            jap (150)           139442  A

                                Format  dynamic
Collation   utf8_general_ci
Rows    139,442
Row length ø    315
Row size ø  468 B
Next Autoindex  140,951

Data    42,945.5    KiB
Index   20,816.0    KiB
Total   63,761.5    KiB
```

Comment: Please add the explain plans for both the queries to eliminate any guess work :)

Answer (score 0):

does joining speeds up your query?

```
SELECT * 
FROM   jap a INNER JOIN `eng-jap` b ON
            a.japanses = b.jap
```

Comment: it says there is a synthax error in your query John, and i dont know how to fix it because i never have used inner join

Comment: sorry I forgot to inlcude `ON`. trying it again.

Comment: i was able to research inner join, and surprisingly it makes the jap query work quickly like the eng one. i guess if its faster than my current queries i will impliment this over my where in quieries. however, though i have a solution to my problem, i still wonder why my one old query worked and the other didnt

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting this is because of the comparison of columns involving non latin characters. Perhaps that has to do with the collation and character set defined on the db. Try with `utf8_bin`.

```
ALTER DATABASE `myDb` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE 'utf8_bin';
```

Binary string comparisons are faster and may make sense in your case. I'm sure in this case english and japanese queries should come up with the same speed.

Also use `JOIN`s as John points out

**Edit:** To answer OP's comments,

```
SELECT * FROM eng WHERE english NOT IN (SELECT eng FROM `eng-jap`);
```

can be more efficiently written as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   eng c 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `eng-jap` t WHERE c.english = t.eng);
```

or

```
SELECT     c.* 
FROM       eng c 
LEFT JOIN `eng-jap` t ON c.english = t.eng 
WHERE      t.eng IS NULL;
```

I can't be sure about which works faster, I assume `JOIN` but in my testing `NOT EXISTS` was faster. May be all that is data dependent. Try yourself.

Comment: one more thing i need is i also use "WHERE NOT IN" so how do i do this sort of "opposite" with JOIN?

Comment: "i tried doing SELECT * FROM jap INNER JOIN `eng-jap` ON `jap`.japanese != `eng-jap`.jap" but it didnt like the NOT EQUALS sythax

Comment: @user1397417 I updated my answer. Its a bit tricky where you have use `IS NULL` syntax. Its a kind of `INTERSECT`/`EXCEPT` feature that's missing in MySQL, so we have to manually do it with LEFT JOINS

Comment: @user1397417 In SO answers should deal with the question posted. What you asked now should be a separate question, though I have edited my answer.

Comment: @user1397417 I'm curious to know if you had changed collation of your database and if it helped! Kindly reply.. :)

Comment: i did try changing it, but it didnt help the original query. also i just noticed. this JOIN query can return one english or japanese sentence MORE THAN ONCE if its finds it more than one in the eng-jap. and the select where column in does not do that. So unless there is an addition to the query that can prevent this i may need to abandon the join and go back to where in. though that would mean the jap query doesnt work still with where in

Comment: @user1397417 there is a prevention for that. You can use group by or distinct to the original join query. Also what about the `NOT EXISTS` query? That too returns duplicates?

Comment: i image that:

    SELECT     c.* 
FROM       jap c 
LEFT JOIN `eng-jap` t ON c.japanese = t.jap
WHERE      t.jap IS NULL;

would be the jap version of :

SELECT     c.* 
FROM       eng c 
LEFT JOIN `eng-jap` t ON c.english = t.eng 
WHERE      t.eng IS NULL;

but it does not work, it returns

#1104 - The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay

Comment: i put SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1; above my query, also tried just running this as a separate query, but it still gives me the same message

Comment: actually i got the query to run finally but it times out. kind of exactly like the original WHERE column IN query only on the jap side would time out. i would REALLY like to know whats causing that

Comment: @user1397417 "it returns `#1104 - The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay `" What is this, some error message you get? You may make it another question. Ya your query for japanese adapted from english is sound, nothing wrong.

Comment: @user1397417 I think you have indexed only eng column in `eng-jap` table. Try giving eng and jap column and index together

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19471/discussion-between-nawfal-and-user1397417)

Comment: the index in eng-jap is eng (150) jap (150) 150 chars of each. its definitely an index on both.

Comment: @user1397417 I am missing something. Could you please post create table and insert values to your question if those are reproduce-able for even small number of values?

Comment: i dont understand what you want me to post. how do i post "create table" you mean some example data from the table?

Comment: @user1397417 I mean the table definition and few values to insert. Its called DDL. It would look like: `CREATE TABLE `config` (
 `id` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 `value` INT(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;`

`insert into ..... values (...........);` etc

Comment: I am asking so that we can test it from our machines

Comment: i dont know where i can find anything like that in phpmyadmin? but i can give some of data for example:
彼は銀行で働いています。----he works in a bank.
どこに行きますか？----where are you going to?
どこに行きますか？----where are you going?
すぐに伝票をお持ちします。----i'll bring you the bill immediately.
そういう印象を与えるつもりではなかったんです。----i didn't mean to give you that impression.
そういう印象を与えるつもりではなかったんです。----i didn't mean to give that impression.
午後はずっと友人とおしゃべりをして過ごした。----i spent the whole afternoon chatting with friends.
彼は嫌な思い出が消えることを願っている。----he wishes to erase bad memories.

Comment: @user1397417 we can not test it with this kind of data. What is the MySQL client u r using? Try searching how to get ddl of your ide..